# Use jQuery To Change Background Image URL ( Added Using Inline CSS With PHP ) On Mobiles

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have checked previous answers however each relate to adding both images which isn't possible in this case as the default ( desktop ) image is already added inline using PHP code.

I need to change the image URL on mobiles using jQuery without modifying the HTML which is generated using PHP. This is what i have which doesn't work as the image is added using inline CSS WITH PHP NOT from using pure CSS in the style sheet.

As i cannot replicate using PHP to add the default image with inline CSS, its not possible to replicate exactly what is going on.

```js
$(window).resize(function() {

    if ($(window).width() < 600) {
   
   $( '.div-background' ).css("background-image", "url('//i.ibb.co/QY97QZ6/b.jpg')")
    
}

});
```

```css
.div-background { 
    background-image: url('https://i.ibb.co/sjtFBQb/image.jpg'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   height: 100vh;
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div-background"><h1>HEADING</h1></div>
```

I have also tried jQuery `.attr('style'`

Comment: Did you try checking for console errors?? Additionally check if your image is actually being applied or not bcoz it maybe that your image has a wrong URL or has a size of 0px , additionally it would be better to do this with css media queries

Comment: Are you actually resizing the page after it loads? And are you loading jQuery before your `resize` listener? Maybe try just the `.css()` call on page load. i.e. Ensure you're loading jQuery first, then just `$(function() { $('div.div-background').css('background-image', "url('//i.ibb.co/QY97QZ6/b.jpg')"); });`

Comment: why you dont use media querys?

Comment: the resize function isn't the problem. The problem relates to using jQuery changing the image when the original image is added inline using PHP code. The fiddle uses pure CSS to add the default image because i can't use PHP to add it inline in a fiddle as fiddles don't work with PHP.

Comment: I want to use the same class. If i use media queries to remove the desktop image, then i have to add back all the CSS with the mobile image. I only want to change the image URL inline and use jQuery to do this.

Comment: You're saying it's added inline using PHP - is it just the CSS that's printed inline (like `div.background-div { background-image: url('<?php echo $imgSrc ?>'); }`? Or are you printing an inline image tag like `<img src='url.jpg'>` and trying to change its parent div's background-image? If the former, then your snippet will work - the resize is the problem - if I copy your snippet to an answer, and just remove the resize function, it changes the image as expected. With the resize function, it does not change the image. If the latter, then you need to change the image's `src` attribute.

Comment: Re-reading my comment it sounded snarky, but I'm really just trying to help out. If PHP prints an image tag `<?php echo "<img src='url.jpg'>"; ?>` (which isn't technically CSS) you can modify the image using `$('img').attr('src', 'otherUrl.jpg');`. In the same fashion `<div style='background-image: url("<?php echo $imgUrl ?>");'></div>`, or similar, can be modified with `$('div').css('background-image', 'url("otherUrl.jpg")');`. Same goes for `<?php echo "div { background-image: url('url.jpg'); }" ?>`.

Comment: This should help, just try resizing the output viewport (bottom-right), the image should update as expected. I added some comments for different situations, too: https://jsfiddle.net/9sv4uark/

Comment: Thanks @mark.hch however i don't want to modify the HTML Only use jQuery and CSS

Comment: In the Fiddle, the HTML was a reference, just there to show how the JS works. Your accepted answer doesn't have a resize listener or the screen width check. That Fiddle does though. Your code would work the same as the accepted answer without the resize function and screen check... I even tried it here, in the Snippet editor...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$( '.div-background' ).css({
  "background": "url('//i.ibb.co/QY97QZ6/b.jpg')"
});
```

Comment: Works, thanks. I assume the background property overrides the background-image property. The only problem i need to fix now is to show the default image when the screen is > 600. Can this be done without adding the image back as its already generated by the PHP?

Comment: You can use window.width

Comment: What i've found is the default image will display when you return back above the mobile screen width if you expand the browser slowly but not always.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding "!important" to the end of the jQuery command like:

```
$( '.div-background' ).css("background-image", "url('//i.ibb.co/QY97QZ6/b.jpg') !important")
```